# Thieves Guild Special Job Bug

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I completed enough thieves guild radiant quests to get a "special" job from Delvin.  I talked to Delvin to get the special job, and there was nothing added to my quest log.  Now every time I get near him he tells me my work has been noticed and that we got a special job, but I can't get a dialog to appear with him.

When I talk to Vex, she says I have to complete Delvin's special job before I can get anymore work.

Knowns.

1. Quest is not in my log.
2. Reloading a previous save game is not an option.
3. I left Riften and did another series of quests and was gone for about a week of game time.
4. The main quest line is complete.
5. The thieves guild (nightingale) quest line is complete, though I may not have the thieves guild armor anymore as I preferred the dark brotherhood gear.
6. It is on the XBOX 360, so the console is not available.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try going to the people in the major cities who are the starting point of the quests, outlined by this guide:

[http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thieves_Guild_(Skyrim)#Special_Jobs](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Thieves_Guild_%28Skyrim%29#Special_Jobs)

**NOTE:** There are spoilers and walk throughs on this site.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer.  In the end what happened was I killed Erikur who was supposed to give me the quest.